# Tensorflow Keras URL fetch failure for Training Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to import my training dataset for my CNN (30,000 images), but there's something about this line that breaks the program.

```
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=dataset_url, 
                                   fname='functionidentifier', 
                                   untar=True)
```

Here's the full code block for more context:

```
dataset_url = "https://barisciencelab.tech/functionidentifier.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin = dataset_url,
                                   fname = "functionidentifier",
                                   untar = True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

It was working just last week, but suddenly broke: [image]

Some things I tried:

- Changing extension of my training set from `.tar.gz` to `.zip` and `.tar.tar` and `.tgz`.
- Unit testing (all other parts of code are fine; they're just importing stuff anyway)
- Exact same code in a new Google Colab Notebook and Jupyter Notebook. Neither worked.
- Checked the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images). My code is **verbatim** the same! The *only* thing that's different is *literally* my URL. That's it.

Nothing worked. And no, I can't manually download the whole training set and do this locally (big-time hassle).

#### MWE ([**Full Code**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1c25FpjrmoBglMta5rW-CgYkM6UfZiSss?usp=sharing))

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install numpy
pip install matplotlib
!git clone https://github.com/Refath/SinusoidalAnalyzer.git
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://barisciencelab.tech/TrainingSet.tar.gz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin = dataset_url, fname = "TrainingSet", untar = True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

Folks in the SO Chat valiantly tried to debug the issue as well, but to no avail. If anyone can help, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me three solid days. In the end, here's what worked:

```
import os
import pathlib

!wget https://barisciencelab.tech/FunctionIdentifier.zip
!unzip FunctionIdentifier.zip

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname('FunctionIdentifier.zip'), 'FunctionIdentifier')

data_dir = pathlib.Path(PATH)
```

Here's the output:
[image]

And of course, it goes on for 30,000 lines.

How did I come up with this solution? After combing through the web, I stumbled upon the `403 – Forbidden` code, different from my `406--Not Acceptable` code, but nonetheless worth a look. I tried porting the solution over and after some modifications (i.e., I define the training/test/validation set parameters separately and feed the `PATH` into `data_dir`).

Also, thanks to @Kevin & @AndrasDeak for spending a significant amount of time helping me debug.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing a previous version of TF in the colab notebook

```
pip install tensorflow==2.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Or maybe your URL is no longer reachable from the colab VM. Try to ping its ip, you can run terminal commands with `!ping "IP"`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the idea. Let me try it right now.

Comment: It still doesn't work: https://i.imgur.com/B1Pnrc0.png

Comment: Run `!pip install tensorflow==2.x` the ! was missing, sorry

Comment: Nope, still not working. I just reverted from tf `2.6` to `2.5.1`, but still getting that URL Fetch Error. Any other ideas? https://i.imgur.com/pTYfjWG.png

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future battling with this issue:

I came across this problem as well. I did some digging and found that the problem was that I didn't have the right certificates installed for Python3. Fairly easy fix on a Mac - run the file located at `Applications>Python 3.X>Install Certificates.command` and that should do the trick.

Not sure if this problem pops up on other OSs or not but I'd imagine the fix is similar.

Comment: If you feel my problem is common, please give it a upvote.